# Generate Reports of User data in android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Database Image]

Image contains the database. I want to generate a report of user Attendance 
 of all dates.As an admin of the app,I need the user attendance record in the form 
 of Report. I am working with Firebase and have no experience  on how to generate reports in android.

Kindly help in this regard.

Comment: Any one here to help.

Comment: I like that `Ask Question` tab in your screenshot. by the way here on *Stackoverflow*, you have to put some code that you have tried. Everyone can help you but no one can do code for you.

Comment: Yeah thats right.But i want to read some basic steps i mean some resources that can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this link

https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/tut-send-app-data-to-a-web-spreadsheet-google-sheets/

I make spreadsheet in my project using firebase.It contains all data of company and store in spreadsheet.

So,you make same thing like this link.

It work like when user enter some data in firebase at that time call this retrofit web service and enter data in spreadsheet.

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: It realy help me .Thank you.

Comment: Most Welcome ^_^